# Batch copy, rename and overwrite newest file from one dir to another

Tags: batch-file

I've found a way to copy the newest file in a directory to another one, using a batch file in Windows. However, I would like your help in figuring out how to then rename the copied file and overwrite old ones.

```
@echo off
set source="D:\Backup"
set target="D:\tmp"

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.csv /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END
:END
```

The idea is that the source Backup folder contains incremental backups with date and time added. I'd like the result to have a constant name, say `raw.csv` so that I can operate with it in Excel.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want a precise target name, why don't you use it?

Comment: Would love to. Could you help me with the proper syntax, please?

Comment: `COPY "%source%\%%I" "%target%\raw.csv"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    set "source=D:\Backup"
    set "target=D:\tmp"

    FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('
        DIR "%source%\*.csv" /A-D /O-D /B
    ') DO COPY "%source%\%%I" "%target%\raw.csv" & echo %%I & GOTO :END

:END
```

As commented, just include the target name in the copy operation.

I've also changed your variable definitions. Unless there is a good reason for doing it, when working with paths it is better *not* to include the quotes in the variable values (later it is harder to work with them). Just quote the assignment (to prevent problems with special characters or final spaces) and later, when required, quote the file system reference.

```
set "source=d:\backup"
    ^................^

set "target=D:\tmp"
    ^.............^

dir "%source%\*.csv"
    ^..............^

COPY "%source%\%%I" "%target%\raw.csv"
     ^............^ ^................^
```

Comment: Tried your suggestions, but ran into some issues. The source directory is actually a tad longer and there are spaces in the name. I tried running the batch file in CMD and it returned an error message that it can't find the file. I added quotes to the path like this `"source="D:\Google Drive\Backup""`, and now it says that it can't find the file, this time, however, displaying the actual name of the latest .csv file in the source folder.

Comment: @zkvvoob, please, check the quoting. it is not `set "var="value""`, it is `set "var=value"`

Comment: Did what you suggested, but the same error appears, that the file cannot be found.

Comment: @zkvvoob, note that I changed the quotes in the `set` commands, the `dir` command and the `copy` command.